# Array.prototype.Map - C# IEnumerable Equivalent

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, ienumerable

I can't figure out on how to map a list of string in `c#`,

can I have something similar this js:

```
var items = [12, 23, 14, 15, 65, 66, 33];

var ids = items.map(id => `post-${id}`);
```

but using `IEnumerable<string>` in `C#`:

```js
IEnumerable<string> ids = Product.GetRelatedProductsIds();

var posts = ??
```

Comment: With LINQ: `var posts = ids.Select(s => "post-" + s)`

Comment: What should be the result, what is `posts`? Is that a IDictionary or IEnumerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] items = new int[] { 12, 23, 14, 15, 65, 66, 33 };

IEnumerable<string> ids = items.Select(x => $"post-{x}");
```

`IEnumerable.Select()` is your `map()` equivalent.

Comment: is Syntax `$"post-{x}"` available in all C# Versions?

Comment: @Hitmands, no, [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) was introduced in C# 6.